# RDLC reports : find hyperlinks per page when displayed in reportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc, reportviewer

I'm new to Microsoft reporting stuff and needs some help! Here is the context :

We are formating rdlc reports based on datasets, and we use the reportViewer object to display it in an aspx page. We need to have hyperlinks in the report that calls another page or web service (not decided yet). The hyperlinks are on a specific type of data inside table cells, lets call them IDs. A report page can contains many or no hyperlinks, depending on the dataset obtained.

So far no problem, but here's the catch : We need to pass a list of IDs to the page/web service that contains all the availables IDs **in the report page**. So I need a way to scan the pages of the formated report to get that list of IDs. How?

So far I tried to :

- Define a javascript function in the aspx that would scan the report DOM for IDs, and call this function in the "go to url" action expression of the table cell. The javascript is executed when I click the hyperlink, but the function defined in the aspx page is not found.
- Write all the javascript to scan the page inside the expression of the "go to url" action, but I realised than when I click on the link, the javascript is executed in a blank page, not in the page containing my report, so I dont have access to the report html.

I want to try :

- Tell the client than this is not a good Idea :)
- Define a javascript function in the aspx page, and execute it when the report is finished to load. This function would then scan the page for all IDs, build a list and asign it to a parameter in every links in the report page. However, I'm warry that I may encounter a security problem accessing the report DOM.
- Look more closely at the vba "Custom Code" section available in the report properties. This seems promising, but so far all examples I seen where calling customs functions with data from a single dataset row as parameters. I need to have access to all dataset rows contained in the formated page.
- Look more closely at the .Net api to see if I can find out how the dataset will be spread over pages, so I could build my hyperlinks and replace them before sending it client side.

The problem i'm facing is really the "per page" thing. Did you done this and what is the best way to do it?

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT :** Forgot to mention than reports all execute multiples grouping on the dataset prior to render, so I cannot estimate the data presented in a page by counting x elements per page. It needs to be done after the dataset is chewed by the rdlc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My other solution uses dom traversing using jquery.

I added a column header with some hook text (`="@HOOK@"`) to help me find the table.  You can find other means to detect your table if that one isn't suitable.
[I also made sure header stays visible during paging](http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/repeat-table-header-on-each-page-in-ssrs/).

The code that traverses the table is defined in the aspx page and called using go to url using `="javascript:functionName()"`

[Screenshot of working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAwzs.png) (ask me if you want me to upload the working project)

Solution :

### Aspx page

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:scriptmanager runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
    Your aspx page : 
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Height="585px" Width="1007px">

        <LocalReport EnableHyperLinks="true" ReportPath="Report1.rdlc">
            <DataSources>
                <rsweb:ReportDataSource Name="DataSet1" DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1"></rsweb:ReportDataSource>
            </DataSources>
        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>

    <asp:objectdatasource runat="server" selectmethod="GetData" typename="stackOverFlow1.ToolsDataSetTableAdapters.MOCK_DATATableAdapter" id="ObjectDataSource1"></asp:objectdatasource>
</form>
<script>
    function getCurrentIds() {
        //get latest table containing my hook
        var data = $("table:contains('@HOOK@')").eq(-1).find("tr").map(function (index) {
            if (index > 1) {
                $row = $(this);
                //hide the hook and find the contents of the second td
                $row.find("td:first").hide();
                var id = $row.find("td:nth-of-type(2)").text();
                // console.log(id);
                return id;
            }
        }).get();
        return data.join(",");
    }
</script>
```

### Go to url action

```
="javascript:alert('current page ids using javascript :' + getCurrentIds())"
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts ! You demonstrated than the ReportViewer inner links can execute a javascript function contained in the aspx page, wich is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Thanks, glad you got your solution !

Answer (score 0):

I understand your "per page" problem. Solving it the javascript way is possible, I haven't had your problem

> The javascript is executed when I click the hyperlink, but the function defined in the aspx page is not found.

Tell me if you want to investigate this path further.

My preferred solution uses a different approach: set fixed number of rows per page, then inside a custom code function, using Vb Take and Skip functions along with current page number, you can get the currently shown rows out from the big dataset. You finally use them in your hyperlink action.

I tested this out and it works fine. 
[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bchzL.png)  and [the working RDL and corresponding dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/utfe0tva4mvsc78/solution.zip?dl=0)(using the same thing in an RDLC should work just fine)

* Mock data from mockaroo.com

Comment: Thanks Yassine for your answer. Unfortunately, the reports all execute multiple grouping on the datasets, so I cannot scan the dataset to define hyperlinks before it was formated by the report. I will edit my question to mention it.

Comment: What I mean by "the function defined in the aspx page is not found" is that the "go to url" action consider the defined expression as an url that is opened in a blank tab, so the javascript defined in the expression is executed in this blank tab...

Comment: My solution doesn't involve data manipulation "before", it's actually done inside the report itself, take a look at report custom code. 
But anyways, take a look at the second javascript solution.

Comment: Thank you ! I will grant you the Bounty for your javascript solution, but would you be kind enough to elaborate how to "get the currently shown rows out from the big dataset" in custom code? As I mentionned, all examples I seen where receiving a single value as parameter. I would favor the vb custom code option if possible...

Comment: I think that with enough trial and error, you can manage to have multi value parameter as your function's parameter, the example I gave you, I created a report parameter that takes data from the dataset (default values from dataset).

Comment: _ couldn't edit previous comment..._ 
The dataset value is set to the ID field. I then join the values of that parameter and pass them to custom code function as a string, along with current page (wich is `CEILING(RowNumber("DataSet1")/20 )`  20 being the number of rows per page).
The custom code then skips `20*pageNumber` and takes 20 and returns the result